# Correct the headers for a service stack rest service sending json as a raw string

Tags: c#, javascript, backbone.js, servicestack

I have trouble with the headers of a simple call of a backbone collection fetch using a service stack backend.

the returned response looks like a json but is just a raw string and backbone don't fetch the collection.

I have notice that the fetch call always result in a error, this is odd since a curl request of the same URL let me check that is all good and I reviving a 200 OK code.

**Edited:** added the complete response

A call of curl and the received output

the header of the response

```
> GET /tickets?format=json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.25.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.25.0 zlib/1.2.5
> Host: 192.168.1.50
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 13:09:35 GMT
< Server: Mono.WebServer.XSP/2.8.0.0 Win32NT
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,69 Win32NT/.NET
< Set-Cookie: ss-id=URB3Ss34BE2FBliYDXEpBQ==; path=/
< Set-Cookie: ss-pid=HAfI68bmXU6jRdTiH0WEBA==; expires=Sat, 19-Jun-2032 13:06:26
 GMT; path=/
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 459
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
* HTTP/1.0 connection set to keep alive!
< Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The json received as raw string

```
[{"id":1,"urgencia":"Normal","fecha":"\/Date(-62135580600000- 0430)\/","ultimaActualizacion":"\/Date(-62135580600000-0430)\/","titulo":"Error 101","descripcion":"Al encender el equipo retorna error 101","status":"A","causas":[],"adjuntos":[],"operadores":[],"citas":[],"estados":[],"comentarios":[{"id":1,"fecha":"\/Date(-62135580600000-0430)\/","editado":"\/Date(-62135580600000-0430)\/","descripcion":"este es un comentario","status":" ","comentarios":[]}]}]
```

So how do I set the headers in service stack so the backbone collection understand that is a json response?

**Update:** I think I have found the root of the problem it has something to do with my Nhibernate models as I can't use them directly for the  Rest service, any other model will parse to the correct type. but still I don't know why. will look on this.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) - see if that works first.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis indeed the "Content-Type:application/json" is show in the header of the response but for backbone is just a raw string, at this point I am not sure if this is a problem of the Rest framework wich I doubt or if is a problem of the ajax request :-(

Comment: I haven't used backbone so I don't know how it does model binding, but a raw string would suggest that nothing is parsing the JSON response. I mean, serialized JSON **is** just a string after all...

Comment: Can you post your backbone code that calls the service?

Comment: actually is just a call for fetch but I am handling the callbacks  error and success as it follows collection.fetch({success: onSuccess, error:onError}) you can read more about it [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch)

Comment: @JesúsBracamonte mind posting the JSON response for reference. Don't strip anything as i have to inspect if this is valid json Backbone expects

Comment: @Deeptechtons done, I also post the header of the response.

Comment: It definitely appears that the service stack portion isn't returning an actual JSON response, it's just a string as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem is related with this, is not a header problem as @jonezy told me "even if the header is correct that doesn't mean the response itself is.", Service Stack can't serialize correctly models associated with Nhibernate so I have to do something like [this](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/06/using-nhibernate-with-servicestack/).

A similar problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351451/cant-serialize-nested-nhibernate-entity-for-wcf-web-service)

thanks to all for your help.